# How to resolve `unable to update state`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm using firebase sign in to login to my app. but when i login i get this error on first time login only. if i close and reopen app, this error doesn't show.
my function is

```
 async function confirmCode() {
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(code).then((userData) => {
        setModalVisible(false);
        props.navigation.navigate('mTab', {screen: 'Home'});
        setCode('');
        ToastAndroid.show('User Signed In !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        user = {
          uid: userData.user.uid,
          name: '',
          phone: userData.user.phoneNumber,
          photoURL: userData.user.photoURL,
          fcmToken: token,
        };
        dispatch(set_user(user));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      ToastAndroid.show('Invalid Code !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

This is the error in debugger

```
D:\Native\messengerMuaz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:179 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Comment: It's only a warning. It says it comes from a useEffect which is not being cleaned up on unmount. You'll have to show us the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
  await confirm.confirm(code).then((userData) => {
    setModalVisible(false);
    props.navigation.navigate('mTab', {screen: 'Home'});
    setCode('');
    ToastAndroid.show('User Signed In !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    user = {
      uid: userData.user.uid,
      name: '',
      phone: userData.user.phoneNumber,
      photoURL: userData.user.photoURL,
      fcmToken: token,
    };
    dispatch(set_user(user));
  });
} catch (error) {
  ToastAndroid.show('Invalid Code !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  console.log(error);
}
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your method in an async function like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myMethod = async () => {
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(code).then((userData) => {
        setModalVisible(false);
        props.navigation.navigate('mTab', {screen: 'Home'});
        setCode('');
        ToastAndroid.show('User Signed In !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        user = {
          uid: userData.user.uid,
          name: '',
          phone: userData.user.phoneNumber,
          photoURL: userData.user.photoURL,
          fcmToken: token,
        };
        dispatch(set_user(user));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      ToastAndroid.show('Invalid Code !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  myMethod()
}, [])
```

To make sure that the requests come in order you can introduce a cleanup function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let didCancel = false

  const myMethod = async () => {
    try {
      if(didCancel){
        return 
      }

      await confirm.confirm(code).then((userData) => {
        setModalVisible(false);
        props.navigation.navigate('mTab', {screen: 'Home'});
        setCode('');
        ToastAndroid.show('User Signed In !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        user = {
          uid: userData.user.uid,
          name: '',
          phone: userData.user.phoneNumber,
          photoURL: userData.user.photoURL,
          fcmToken: token,
        };
        dispatch(set_user(user));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      ToastAndroid.show('Invalid Code !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  myMethod()

  return () => {didCancel = true}
}, [])
```

you probably want to add `code` as a dependency since your request depends on it, or keep it empty if you only want to run it on mount. If you want to add `code` update the empty `[]` with `[code]`

Dan explains it here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326

Comment: doesn't work. first of all can't use in useEffect as it will run when component starts/mounts. which will check code at that time but code will be sent later.